# org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```html
<div class="Dropdown-root false is-open"><div class="Dropdown-control postedby_selector" aria-haspopup="listbox"><div class="Dropdown-placeholder">Select</div><div class="Dropdown-arrow-wrapper"><span class="Dropdown-arrow"></span></div></div><div class="Dropdown-menu postedby_options" aria-expanded="true"><div class="Dropdown-option" role="option" aria-selected="false">Self</div><div class="Dropdown-option" role="option" aria-selected="false">Son</div><div class="Dropdown-option" role="option" aria-selected="false">Daughter</div><div class="Dropdown-option" role="option" aria-selected="false">Brother</div><div class="Dropdown-option" role="option" aria-selected="false">Sister</div><div class="Dropdown-option" role="option" aria-selected="false">Friend</div><div class="Dropdown-option" role="option" aria-selected="false">Relative</div></div></div>
```

```html
<div class="Dropdown-control postedby_selector" aria-haspopup="listbox" xpath="1"><div class="Dropdown-placeholder">Select</div><div class="Dropdown-arrow-wrapper"><span class="Dropdown-arrow"></span></div></div>
```

**Note**: profileCreater is a variable which contain string value

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@id='___gatsby']/div[1]/div[7]/form[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]"));

Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
Action val=builder.moveToElement(element).build();

val.perform();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@id='___gatsby']/div[1]/div[7]/form[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]")).click();

Select select=new Select(element);

select.selectByValue(profileCreater);
```

[image]

This is my dropdown and I need to select values from this with which is stored in profileCreater variable. I'm reading this value from the .csv file and storing it in a variable that is profileCreater.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Could you please share the HTML. What concrete issues are you facing? 
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I want to select the dropdown value therefore I'm using the above code but the issue is HTML XPath is in from of span and  I'm not able to select a value using Select Class.Could you please tell me another way to select drop down value?

Comment: @VrushaliGave   As you can see the dropdown does not have select tag so it will not work with Select class. Create Utility method for that. Also the html provided is not proper one to reproduce the case. add the relevant html of the dropdown

Comment: Could please provide me some relative code for this?

Comment: @VrushaliGave As said earlier we need the html code of element to reproduce the case. The html in the above post is not enough

Comment: Yes, I have posted the Html code. Could you please check that code?

Comment: Can you share your site url to recheck ?
You cant use select class for this please share URL here ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this error :

**Use this XPath format for clicking on dropdown : //span[contains(@class,'Dropdown-arrow')]
Note: Use the tag as per your webpage. In my case its span tag**

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'Dropdown-arrow')]")).click();

```
        List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'Dropdown-option')]"));
                
        for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++) {
            if(list.get(j).getText().contains(profileCreater)) {
                list.get(j).click();
                break;
            }
            
        }
```

**profileCreater is variable which contains .csv file data. I'm passing variable data to select the dropdown value.**